# Problems pulling Storyboard from Bitbucket

Tags: git, swift, xcode6, bitbucket, xcode-storyboard

I'm working with another team member in Xcode. We have our Xcode repository in bitbucket.

I cloned the repo from Bitbucket to my local machine. When I open the cloned Xcode project on my machine, all files appear correct except for the Storyboard. The storyboard file,  doesn't open in Xcode, and it appears in red like so:

[image: main.storyboard is red]

I checked the file directory on my machine and the storyboard is definitely in there, but it is not named `Main.storyboard`.

So next in Xcode I went to `File > Add Files to "Project"` to manually add the cloned Storyboard to the Xcode project. This cloned Storyboard file, `Cloned.storyboard`, opens in Xcode but with "No Scenes". This is not correct.

Any suggestions on what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Would it be possible to rename it to Main.storyboard first, before adding it to the project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It automatically checks the boxes next to files to push, however, you need to verify the boxes are checked next to each file you are trying to commit/push.

cheers

Oyy

## Appleseed

Comment: You're right. In Xcode Source Control I forgot to check the box next to main.storyboard to ensure that it committed.